# Infinite loop + Thread.sleep replace cron job

Tags: java, multithreading, cron, sleep, infinite-loop

So I've had an idea in my head today... And I would like to hear some feed-back. I have a Java app which needs to check a directory every 5 minutes. Plain and simple the app needs to run every five minutes.

Seems like a good candidate for cronjob, but I was wondering... why not keep the logic/timing all within the app like so (simplified obviously):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while(true) { // repeatedly execute...
        // do the work/job
        Thread.sleep(600 * 1000); // make the thread sleep for 5 minutes
    }
}
```

One significant downside I see is "How do we *stop* this app once it starts? Deleting it?

Are there any other significant draw-backs to this besides that one?

Should I stop daydreaming and just use cron jobs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A number of significant drawbacks:

- If you ever want to change the polling frequency (i.e. do it every 2 minutes, or every 10 minutes), you have to change the program. This is especially difficult if you have an irregular polling schedule, something like once every 5 minutes on Monday through Friday, but once every 15 minutes on Saturday and Sunday. Sure, you don't *think* your program will ever need to do that, but requirements evolve.
- As you say, killing the process is the only way to stop the program. And killing it in mid-process might be a bad thing. You could of course add some cancel logic, but that's additional development time.
- The program is occupying memory while it's sitting there doing nothing (most of the time). This is a waste of resources. Probably not a huge deal when you're working with a system that has many gigabytes of memory, but it becomes an issue when you're working on embedded systems with limited memory.
- You're wasting your time writing your own scheduling, which you then have to debug and maintain, when there's already a perfectly good scheduler built into the operating system.

I call this program a "catnap program" because it acts just like a cat: it sleeps most of the time, waking up now and then to stretch and maybe bat a string around for a few minutes, and then goes back to sleep. [Programs are not cats](https://blog.mischel.com/2023/02/03/computer-programs-are-not-cats/).

Comment: Well, to be fair, the loop interval could be easily changed if the interval is a var read from the command-line, (or wherever), instead of a literal constant.  Programs are not cats, fair enough, but a cat thread is not necessarily a bad idea:)

Answer (score 3):

You can run a task at fixed rate using [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) and stop it on some action (here by reading `System.in`):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do some work
        }
    }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);  // every 5 minutes

    // when anything is entered, the task is stopped
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String whatever = sc.next();
    // shutdown the executor
    ses.shutdown();
    ses.awaitTermination(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Comment: So the code doesn't block at ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(... ?

Answer (score 2):

A solution like the one suggested has the advantage that it will work on an operating system that does not have `cron` (but every OS will have some kind of scheduler).

On the other hand using `cron` has these advantages:

- The task will be run at the next scheduled time even if it crashes; the solution shown won't run again after a crash until someone restarts it.
- Cron will start running the task again after a reboot; the solution proposed doesn't do that.
- When the task stops and then shuts down periodically, memory leaks are less critical than in a long-running process.

This list could doubtless be made longer by enumerating more features that have been added to OS level job schedulers over time.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a quartz scheduler within my application. link http://quartz-scheduler.org/

it does control, when you start your application it runs, and when your application stops it will stop. Granted there is more setup, but it's pretty flexiable.